# Are the side missions available after completing the Wolfenstein II main story?

Tags: wolfenstein-2-the-new-colossus

The side missions are accessed by using the enigma machine at the hub area. I don't have particular interest in them at the time as all take place in repurposed mission locations to my knowledge, with the same objective to kill a commander (Überkommandant). I would prefer moving to these missions after finishing the campaign and [the DLC](https://store.steampowered.com/app/650410/Wolfenstein_II_The_Freedom_Chronicles__Season_Pass/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finishing the game, you are clearly informed that the Überkommandant missions are available:

[image: screenshot]

all other side missions, including the remaining contraptions, are available as well:

[image: screenshot]